# Serialization of Java Objects

Tags: java, object, networking, serialization, tcp

I'm trying to evaluate the usefulness of using Serialized objects in a Java application I'm developing.  I'm trying to determine if the following makes sense for an Object-serialization implementation, or if I should custom-build the transport.  Here's my scenario:

- Objects will be transported over TCP from one application to another.
- The serialized object will be an instance of a class stored in a common library.

Sample Class:

```
public class Room implements Serializable {
    // Instance Variables
    private Room roomWithinRoom;
    // ...
}
```

So my question is that since I will have several instance variables that reference back to the Room class, can I use Java serialization to accomplish the transfer of Room objects?  If I am able to accomplish this, will the pointers be preserved?

Example:

```
Room mainRoom = new Room();
Room closet = new Room();
mainRoom.addRoom(closet);
```

If I send over the object "mainRoom," will it also serialize and send the "closet" instance (preserving the roomWithinRoom instance variable in mainRoom?)

Thanks a bunch, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java serialization does this really well.  Maybe too well.  I've had great luck writing to files.  With TCP be sure to call `reset` after each write.  Java will send a whole network graph in one go--your object, all the objects references, all they reference, and so on.  One writeObject *can* send gigabytes of data.  But without reset, if the next object you write was included in the first graph, all that will go across will be a reference to the previously sent object.  Any updated data will be ignored.  (Did I mention you should call `reset` after each `writeObject`?)

I'd suggest using the Externalizable interface.  This gives you a bit more control over what gets written.  (Actually, this is done on a class basis, so some classes can be Serializable and some Externalizable with no problem.)  This means you can write in the same format even when the class changes a bit.  It lets you skip data you don't need, and sometimes pass trivial objects as data primitives.  I also use version numbers so newer versions of the class can read stuff written by older versions.  (This is a bit more important when writing to files than with TCP.)  A warning:  when reading a class, be aware that the object reference you just read may *not* reference any data (that is, the referenced object has not be read in yet; you're looking at unitialized memory where the object's data *will* go.).

You'll probably fumble around with this a bit, but it does work really well once you understand it.

Comment: I don't see what TCP has to do with calling reset(), and as he wants references preserved I don't see why you're recommending reset() at all. You don't need Externalizable to overcome class changes: there is a large chapter in the Object Serialization Specification that defines compatibility of various changes, which is far more extensive than most people seem to think, even if they've read it.

Comment: @EJP: You want the references preserved in one write. You send one object, and it includes the rest of its object graph.  This is what you want. Update the objects in the graph and send one across again, and ObjectOutput will note that it's sent them already and do nothing except send a message saying to repeat the previous output.  No new data will get transferred.

Comment: @EJP:  The other problem is that ObjectOutput and Input will never forget an object.  If you send a bunch of unrelated objects, each will go through, but they will all be remembered.  If you're connected for several busy hours this can use up a lot of memory on both ends.  (And if you do repeat an object, the reader gets the first one sent; the latest copy's data won't go through.)

Comment: @EJP: As to Externalizable:  no, you don't need it at all.  I found it useful, so I mentioned it.  It may just be that I'm a control freak.

Comment: Guys, I really appreciate the advice!  For my specific use case, my objects are created once and will not change during the scope of the application, but I feel this discussion is excellent for other developers who may have a different requirement.

Comment: @Ralph He may want references preserved across *all* writes. Absent any evidence to the contrary you have no basis for saying he 'should' reset().

Comment: @EJP:  You seem to be right.  My thinking was that one app talking to another is going to repeat itself after a while, which will eventually result in a train wreck.  In fact, the OP is sending one object graph, period, and doesn't need `reset` at all.  But I'd rather mention `reset` when it's not needed then not mention it when it is.  I did get a bit overly emphatic in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

References will be preserved within the object graph, and any nested objects will also be serialized correctly given they implement the serializable interface, and are not marked transient.

I advise against built in java serialization as it is more verbose than other binary protocols.  Also there is always the *potential* that serialization/deserialization routines could change between runtimes.

For these reasons, I suggest [ProtoBufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). ProtoBuf is small, fast, and can even be used to quickly build serialization/deserialization routines in languages other than Java, given you find a protobuf "compiler" for that language.